# SwiftUI hide navigation bar of UIKit UINavigationController(rootViewController: _)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a SwiftUI view:

```
struct Content View: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Content view")
  }
}
```

And I used menu which created with UIKit. And there my view should be `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController`. For show my swiftUI view I setted my view inside `UINavigationController`:

```
let navigationController = UIHostingController(rootView: Content()).inNavigation()

// inNavigation()
extension UIViewController{
    func inNavigation() -> UIViewController {
        let vc = self
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
        vc.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        vc.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        vc.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        vc.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        vc.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
        vc.navigationController?.accessibilityFrame = .zero
        
        navigationController.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navigationController.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        navigationController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        navigationController.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
        navigationController.accessibilityFrame = .zero
        return navigationController
    }
}
```

I tried to hide navigationBar. But it still showing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` should be in view hierarchy so that could have effect.

Here is worked variant, assuming you inject it into window in `SceneDelegate` (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
extension UIViewController{
    func inNavigation() -> UIViewController {
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        }
        return navigationController
    }
}
```